# How to use regex_search to get the a line of text from two different .txt files

Tags: c++, regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to use this regex pattern `Subject: [\a-zA-Z_0-9]+` in c++ to get this line of text from two different files one being this:

```
Message-ID: <..>
Subject: AAAI-22 General Information
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; ..
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

and the other being

```
Subject: Re: Possible need for … 240
Thread-Topic: Possible need for printout for .. 240
```

however, the regex pattern matches:

```
Subject: AAAI-22 General Information MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; ..Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

for the first text file and for the second file the pattern matches

```
Subject: Re: Possible need for
```

All I want my regex pattern to search for and print out is the `Subject:` and whatever else is in that line and nothing else. How can I do that using `regex_search` and `regex_replace` patterns?

Comment: please show a [mre] of the code you are using

Comment: e.g. [this](https://godbolt.org/z/vPonPe1MP) doesn't reproduce your problem. Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/hWPPd7d9c) what you want?

Comment: or just [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ETcEs4jGT)

Comment: An fyi, the `\a` is the _BEL_ character `\x07` and not the alphabetic character. So `[\a-zA-Z_0-9]+` is really matching `[\x07-zA-Z_0-9]+`

Comment: `[\x07-z]` encompases roughly these 116 characters `!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` It is better to use `\w` as an alternative, which can be considered `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` in the ASCII range. Basically the problem was CRLF is being included. As well as spaces, etc..

Comment: I'm leaving soon if you have any more questions.

Comment: So, you're looking for any line that starts with "Subject:", and you want to print out the contents of that line? Don't use a regular expression for such a simple search. Read a line into a `std::string` and check whether it starts with `"Subject":`. If it does, print out the string.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex pattern to search for Subject line

```
"Subject: .+"
```

Explanation:

- `Subject:`   matches the characters `Subject:`   literally (case
  sensitive).
- `.`matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times